# Problem for Matlab Installation

Tags: installation, matlab, permissions

I install the **Matlab2009a** to my computer successfully and when I try to activate it without using the **internet** (Activate manually without the Internet) and provide the path to license file. Then an error coming out

> Could not complete Activation because the License File could not be written to disk.  You might not have write permission on the License File or the folder. /home/linyulin/licenses/license_ubuntu_161051_R2010a.lic  See your System Administrator for assistance. The specific error message text is:
>
> /home/linyulin/licenses/ license_ubuntu_161051_R2010a.lic (Permission denied).

Thank you very much for your help. I'm really anxious about this problem because I have spent lots of time on this problem and really don't want to mass it up. Thank you again!

Comment: what does the command `ls -la linyulin/licenses/` say?

Answer (score 6):

On Linux you get this error because you don't have permissions for the license folder. An easy way to get past this is by launching the activation script with sudo:

```
cd $MATLAB/R20***/bin/
sudo ./activate_matlab.sh
```

($MATLAB/R20*** is your root MATLAB installation folder)

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
ls -la /home/linyulin/licenses/license_ubuntu_161051_R2010a.lic
```

to see what the permissions are on that file. If you don't own it, you could try

```
sudo chown linyulin /home/linyulin/licenses/license_ubuntu_161051_R2010a.lic
```

If that by itself doesn't make the activation go forward, you can try

```
chmod +x /home/linyulin/licenses/license_ubuntu_161051_R2010a.lic
```

to make it executable, or, failing everything else,

```
chmod 777 /home/linyulin/licenses/license_ubuntu_161051_R2010a.lic
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the instructions given by https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB/R2009b . Essentially, `sudo chown -R linyulin:linyulin .matlab/`. If that doesn't do it you could also do `sudo chown -R linyulin:linyulin licenses/`

Answer (score 0):

do `gksudo ./activate_matlab.sh`

This will most probably solve the permission issues and activate Matlab.

Comment: gksudo is not installed by default in Ubuntu.

Comment: @Braiam That's only started with 13.04/13.10, I believe. Version is not given, but OP could be on 12.04.